# Set names of values in lengthMenu (Page Length Menu) in R DT datatable

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am making a datatable using the R DT package. I would like for the user to be able to decide/control whether to see 24, 48, 72, 96 or all rows in the data.

This can be easily done by setting:

```
lengthMenu = c(24,48, 72, 96, -1),
```

in the option list, where -1 stands for all entries.

Problem is that the user might not know what -1 stands for, and I would therefore like to make it appear as the string "All" in the menu visible to the user.

By looking at the [documentation for lengthMenu](https://datatables.net/reference/option/lengthMenu), I see that this could be done by writing

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
"lengthMenu": [ [10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"] ]
} );
```

But I have no idea how to translate that to R-language. 
I have tried using named list, vectors and arrays but neither worked out.

Below is a simple example:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(iris, options = list(pageLength = 24, 
                  lengthMenu = c(24,48, 72, 96, -1), paging = T))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do. For more info please visit [shiny-examples/018-datatable-options/](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/tree/master/018-datatable-options)

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(iris, options = list(pageLength = 24, 
                        lengthMenu = list(c(24,48, 72, 96, -1), 
                                          c('24', '48', '72','96', 'All')),
                         paging = T))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast. Thank you so much! I didn't think of looking through the Shiny Gallery (examples) first, I mainly focused on the [Github documentation](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/) of DT and [this page](https://datatables.net/reference/). With your answer I now know how to translate the options from the latter page for other properties.